# Selection Sort (Sorting Nodes not Values) in Double Linkedlist

Tags: sorting, linked-list, selection

I am trying to sort a double linkedlist, its node class is Weapon. I already tried the swap method for bubble sort and shell sort, it works fine. I don't know what part is incorrect in this selection sort, I already checked it multiple times. Any suggestion? TIA

```
public Weapon findMax(Weapon aktif){
        Weapon curr = aktif.next;
        Weapon max = aktif;
        while(curr!=null){
            if(curr.stok>max.stok){
                max = curr;
            }
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        return max;
    }

    public void selectionSort(){
        Weapon curr = head;
        while(curr!=null){
            Weapon maks = findMax(curr);
            swap(curr, maks);
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }
```

And here is the swap method

```
// Swap next pointers
    Weapon tempNext = a.next;
    a.next = b.next;
    b.next = tempNext;

    // Update prev pointers of next elements
    if (a.next != null) {
        a.next.prev = a;
    }
    if (b.next != null) {
        b.next.prev = b;
    }

    // Swap prev pointers
    Weapon tempPrev = a.prev;
    a.prev = b.prev;
    b.prev = tempPrev;

    // Update next pointers of prev elements
    if (a.prev != null) {
        a.prev.next = a;
    } else {
        head = a; // Update head if 'a' is now the first element
    }
    if (b.prev != null) {
        b.prev.next = b;
    } else {
        head = b; // Update head if 'b' is now the first element
    }
```